# How to xss attack here

Tags: translation, xss

I have a div with code like this,

```
<div id="someId" data-role="someRole" 
data-ordered-list="[{name: 'Flow', text: '{!$Label.Flow_Data}'}]">

</div>
```

I have a custom Label called Flow_data that has a french translation to: alert(1)
I am trying to have XSS attack here but cannot achieve it. Is it possible to have XSS attack here, and resolve it using JSEncode().

The div is not inside any script tag. It is inside apex:page tag.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're doing with this; poorly written JavaScript libraries that don't escape and use innerHTML can fall victim to an XSS. However, that requires some extra effort. The code, as written, is perfectly safe in Visualforce, because the characters `&"<>` are all encoded, so the browser will not interpret them in a way that allows you to break out of the attribute and run arbitrary code. Even if you could fall victim to an XSS here, the resolution would be either HTMLENCODE or JSINHTMLENCODE, not JSENCODE. You use JSENCODE strictly inside of script blocks.